# Logically Why Can't Change the ParentID for an Object, instead I must change the parent it self?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
//Set Parent ID for the rest of the Reports data sources
this.ReportDataSources.ToList().ForEach(rds => rds.Parent = reportDataSource);
```

Why not can I set the Parent ID directly? what may let LINQ Prevent such an action

```
//Set Parent ID for the rest of the Reports data sources
this.ReportDataSources.ToList().ForEach(rds => rds.ParentID = reportDataSource.ID);
```

Exception Thrown here

```
[Column(Storage="_ParentID", DbType="Int")]
public System.Nullable<int> ParentID
{
    get
    {
        return this._ParentID;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._ParentID != value))
        {
            if (this._Parent.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
            {
                throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
            }
            this.OnParentIDChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._ParentID = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("ParentID");
            this.OnParentIDChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure I debugged it, the exception i posted on the code: throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();, It thrown whenever the ParentId changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unfortunate duplicity between ParentId and Parent; having them disagree is a pain, so it doesn't let you do that. You *can* set just the id though - especially when inserting.

You could try:

```
obj.Parent = null;
obj.ParentId = newParentId;
```

Then they can't be in conflict.

Comment: So what is the point of this property: this._Parent.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue, since I can workaround it?

Comment: @rami - maybe check MSDN; I don't know off the top of my head